# Apache Isis and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, isis

Can someone please help me on setting up Apache Isis to work with MySQL.
I tried to set MySQL database but it doesn't work.

```
isis.persistor.datanucleus.impl.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
isis.persistor.datanucleus.impl.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://<host>/<database>
isis.persistor.datanucleus.impl.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=<username>
isis.persistor.datanucleus.impl.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=<pass>
```

With this I am getting this errors

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post some more of the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception. In my case, it was an issue with the DB server. I am using XAMPP with the included *MariaDB* server (which is a fork of MySQL and should be a binary drop-in replacement for MySQL).

So, if you use MariaDB instead of MySQL, you can try the following steps:

Add the `mariadb-java-client` artifact to the dependency list in the `pom.xml` file (of your webapp project if you have split up your project).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Update the connection driver name and URL scheme (e.g. in the file `isis.properties`):

```
isis.persistor.datanucleus.impl.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
isis.persistor.datanucleus.impl.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/myapp?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Maybe that helps you...